# Creating a custom contact page  -- page-contact.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-contact-form

I'm new to Drupal. I want to create a contact page, so I copied page.tpl.php and renamed it to page-contact.tpl.php. I created some new elements in the page, so I can see that if I click on the "contact" link, I'll know that I went to the correct page.

Right now I don't see any change. Was there something I missed? Do I need to do something in the admin settings so Drupal knows which file I need to open?

I also tried clearing my cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, this is a valid approach. Problem is, you'll be able to create a new layout for your contact page this way, but not necessarily change the contact form. If you wish to alter the form as well, I'd recommend using the `webform` module. It's pretty flexible when it comes to creating contact forms, plus, it creates a node, so you can style it with ease (either in you standard `node.tpl.php` or - even better - in `node-webform.tpl.php`). This is what I usually do.

There might be other solutions too, but it would help if you made it clear what kind of alterations you wish to introduce in your contact page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and use the webform module. I'll see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `cleared my cache` do you mean the browser cache or drupal's cache? Ensure drupal's theme registry has been cleared by going to `/admin/build/themes`, or logging out and back in.

I also recommend trying the [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module as mingos suggests.

Comment: I believe I cleared drupal's cache. I went to admin/settings/performance.

Comment: I think that that cache is difference from the theme registry, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and use the webform module. I'll see if that works.

Comment: Oh ok, let me try to clear drupal's theme registry. Hopefully that'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal core's built in contact module does not use any templates, so you'll have to use something like Webform if you want a per-contact template.